# Could not build module GLKit

Tags: ios, opengl-es, llvm, glkit, ios8.3

I have an iOS application , after upgrading my ipad4 from 7.1 to 8.3 and xcode  6.2 to 6.3.2 i started to get build error for GLKit .

I get an error 'Definition of builtin function'  for following functions

- __wfi
- __wfe
- __sev
- __sevl
- __yield

Cleaning project , deleting derived data or changing deployment target did not solve any problem .

[image: Unable to build GLKIT]

Comment: find the defions of __wfi in your code, and delete them.

Comment: what is the anwer here?